# How to create a tag such as 'adjective-ending'?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just posted a question about verb and adjective endings. [How many verb/adjective endings are there?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/286/how-many-verb-adjective-endings-are-there)

There are tags 'verb', 'verb-endings' and 'adjective', but not 'adjective-endings'. Should there be one, and what's the protocol for adding it?

Comment: All you need to do to create a tag is type it in (as free text) when you ask a question.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that the first time and nothing happened. I've just tried it again and it worked. My motivation is that I would tag questions about the  semantics of verbs and adjectives as 'verb' and 'adjective' respectively, and questions about their syntax as 'verb-endings' and 'adjective-endings'.

Answer (score 3):

There is no protocol to create any tag. As the link on [Create Tags](https://korean.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) shows, you can create a tag when you have more than 150 reputation points.

> **How do I create a new tag?**
>
> Simply enter a new tag with your question and it will be created. When
>   creating your new tag, bear in mind that tags ...
>
> must be no longer than 25 characters must use the character set a-z
>   0-9 + # - .
>
> **What happens when a new tag is created?**
>
> The new tag will now be available for all other community members to
>   use, without needing the new tag privilege. It will also show up in
>   the moderator tools new tag report.
>
> However, note that:
>
> - on some sites, new tags will be automatically culled and removed from
>     the system if they are not used by at least 1 other question in a 6
>     month period.
> - meta tags, tags that cannot stand alone as the only tag
>     on a question, are not allowed.
>
> **Please create new tags responsibly!** (emphases mine)

Note: This question was asked before the privilege required to create tags was lower than 150.